# Download a file using MemoryStream SFTP (SSH.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, stream, sftp, ssh.net

I'm trying to download a file from `SFTP` using the library `SSH.NET`, however I can not save the file in a folder, I wanted to work with it in MemoryStream format, how can I do this?

Below is the code where I connect to sftp and try to get it using sftpFile.

```
using (SftpClient sftp = new SftpClient(url, usuario, senha))
{
    sftp.Connect();                  
    sftp.ChangeDirectory("/HOURLY"); 

    if (sftp.Exists(nomeArquivo))
    {
        var arquivoSftp = sftp.Get(nomeArquivo);
    }

    sftp.Disconnect();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Reopen vote reason? I can reopen it if this duplicate isn't right, but it seems to fit what OP is asking?

Comment: In case I would need to download the file but using MemoryStream, I didn't want to save it to a directory. For this reason it is not duplicated.

Comment: @Guillherme The `DownloadFile` method takes the base `Stream` object, be it `FileStream` (as in the linked question) or `MemoryStream`. Once the download method is complete, just seek to position 0 in your memory stream and you should be good to go.

Comment: Or use `Open` => I've added another question to the list of duplicates.